# Get system startup time (without reading /proc/uptime)

Tags: php, linux

I cannot open `/proc/uptime` due to `open_basedir` restriction.

The command `uptime` is too old and doesn't have the `-s` flag support.

How can I - in PHP - get time when the server started?

My current code is this, but it does not work on the production server (for the reasons mentioned above):

```
public static function getBootTime()
{
    $tmp = explode(' ', file_get_contents('/proc/uptime'));
    return ((int) ((time() - intval($tmp[0])) / 10)) * 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the -s flag to determine the uptime. If you do something like this you have the time the server is running:

```
$tmp = explode(' ', exec('uptime'));
$uptime = $tmp[2]; // something like 2:14 (hh:mm)
```

nb: an alternative would be to use the `who -b` command, which will print out the last system boot time.

Comment: okay parsing regular "uptime" could work, but "who -b" prints empty string for some reason (it's some bizarre debian on arm, so maybe that's why)

Answer (score 1):

ps -eo pid,etime | grep -w "1"

grep for the uptime of init is another way. Here etime is the elapsed time after the init process is started.

Answer (score 0):

the commands top and w gives you the uptime as well. Are you not able to use one of them. But they get the information again from /proc/uptime